# What does this warning/information box mean and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Using the default *Source Control* plugin Git in Visual Studio 2019, I get the following warning/information box:

[image: Warning message]

> #### Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Source Control - Git
>
> The current solution has projects that are located outside the
>   solution folder. These projects will not be source controlled in the
>   Git repository. To add all the projects to a single Git repository
>   please consolidate all projects under a single folder.
>
> `[OK]`   `[Cancel]`

Alas, the project is an individual `.csproj` that isn't tied to any solution file. It is two folder levels down relative to the root of the (Git) worktree.

My guess is that the `Source Control - Git` in the message indicates that it originates from the (default) Source Control plugin. Curiously there appears to be no difference between <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> which sort of makes sense because allegedly it's purely informational.

Regardless: how can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Make sure all your project files/folders are in the same root folder as the repo?

Comment: @evolutionxbox uhm you mean _in_ the worktree root (i.e. directly in the root) or _underneath_ (i.e. any subfolder) the worktree root? Because the latter is already true, as I pointed out in my question. And it seems odd that the plugin should care however deep inside the worktree I store my projects and solutions, right?

Comment: I don't use VS so I'm just guessing, but if everything's under the appropriate directory tree, perhaps there's an existing Git repository in there and VS is going to treat it as a submodule.

Comment: @torek the solution does indeed have projects outside of the current repo by way of a submodule. And that's exactly how I want it to be (well, not I, but those who make the decisions around here ... I would avoid submodules for different reasons).